Visionary Render Lua, Moving Assembly
I'm attempting to control an assembly in VisRen using an event script (e.g. to move forward, the script is activated when W is pressed/ held).
I've currently got a very simple script, simply using a while loop to keep adding 0.01 to the x/y/z axis, however this is causing the script to crash since it's just continuously adding onto itself.
Does anyone know of a way to make it move at a specified velocity instead? Would be a huge help, thank you. :)
